# At first I was afraid I'd be petrified

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> At first I was afraid I'd be petrified
>   Kept thinking I would never live if you were in my sights
>   But then I asked the gods for help, stopped feeling sorry for myself
>   Got some shoes to fly,
>   So I'll hold my shield up high
>   But you can't see me,
>   And I won't see you
>   I'm not some helpless little victim to be tricked by you
>
> Weren't you the one who tried to make me calcify
>   Do you think I'd crumble
>   Did you think I'd lay down and die?
>
> Oh no, not I, I will survive
>   Oh, as long as I have the gods above, I know I'll stay alive
>   I've got all my life to live
>   And I've got all my love to give and I'll survive
>   I will survive, hey, hey

Who is the singer? And no, I don't mean Gloria Gaynor.
Partial credit (i.e. an upvote) if you get who the subject of the song is, but the answer I'm looking for is the singer.

> Honestly the only reason I wrote this was because there was a great 'petrified' pun to be made here.

Comment: Very cool! I actually laughed out loud. Like the "fly" disco shoes.

Comment: Aside from my answer th petrified bit makes me think petrol

Comment: For the title I dropped in; was not disappointed with what was within.

Comment: Great, now I can't get the song out of my head. Where's my karaoke?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is

> Medusa

Sung by

> Perseus

```
At first I was afraid I'd be petrified
Kept thinking I would never live if you were in my sights
```

> Her gaze petrifies

```
But then I asked the gods for help, stopped feeling sorry for myself
Got some shoes to fly,
```

> He recieved winged sandals from Hermes

```
So I'll hold my shield up high
But you can't see me,
And I won't see you
I'm not some helpless little victim to be tricked by you
```

> Used his shield, the future Aegis, to view Medusa only through reflections, and remain unseen via an invisibility cap

```
Weren't you the one who tried to make me calcify
Do you think I'd crumble
Did you think I'd lay down and die?
```

> He was not turned to stone, but instead won

```
Oh no, not I, I will survive
Oh, as long as I have the gods above, I know I'll stay alive
I've got all my life to live
And I've got all my love to give and I'll survive
I will survive, hey, hey
```

> He was victorious, through the blessings of Olympians

Answer (score 0):

At first I was afraid I'd be petrified

Kept thinking I would never live if you were in my sights

But then I asked the gods for help, stopped feeling sorry for myself

> It is the song that Lot sings to God.
>   Lot fear the wrath of God upon Sodom and Gomorrah

Got some shoes to fly,

So I'll hold my shield up high

> Lot receives the angels to assure him that he will be saved

But you can't see me,

And I won't see you

I'm not some helpless little victim to be tricked by you

> Lot denies God by his desire to destroy Sodom

Weren't you the one who tried to make me calcify

Do you think I'd crumble

Did you think I'd lay down and die?

> The punishment of turning people into statues wing salt was already known.

Oh no, not I, I will survive

Oh, as long as I have the gods above, I know I'll stay alive

I've got all my life to live

And I've got all my love to give and I'll survive

I will survive, hey, hey

> Lot is sure to be saved. His wife will be punished for turning to look at the destroyed city. It is calcified.

Comment: interesting answer, but I was specifically talking about perceus, not lot, and the gods references were to greek mythology not the bible